# Understanding what a topological germ is

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I have trouble understanding what is a germ in a topological space.
 I have to mention that i don't have knowledge about this concept in any other area (complex analysis or others), so please don't answer by this means. 
The definitions that have been given to me are this:

---

Let $(X,\tau_1)$ and $(Y,\tau_2)$ be topological spaces, and $x\in X$. 
Let $\xi(x)$ denote the set of all neighbourhoods of $x$.

- Let $U,V\in\xi(x)$, $f:U\rightarrow Y$ and $g:V\rightarrow Y$ two maps. 
  We say that $f$ and $g$ are germ-equivalent at $x$ if $\exists W\in\xi(x)\;:\;W\subseteq U\cap V,\;\forall y\in W,\;f(y)=g(y)$.
- Let $A,B\subseteq X$.
   We say $A$ and $B$ are germ-equivalent at $x$ if $\exists U\in\xi(x):A\cap U=B\cap U$.

This two relations define two equivalence relations.
And what i wanted to prove is that $[A]_x=[B]_x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $[\chi_A]_x=[\chi_B]_x$.
If this is not true i will be grateful if someone can provide a counterexample.
I have to mention that i'm newbie in this so maybe i have made some mistakes.

Comment: Did you mean $W\subseteq$ instead of $W\in$ (same for $U$)?

Comment: @DavidP By $W\in\xi(x)$ i mean a neighbourhood of x. I'm denoting $\xi(x)$ as the set of all neighbourhoods of x.

Comment: @Gae.S. thank you so much, i'm not sure if I should edit the post once again to put your remarks about the non-emptyness .(Curiously the definition i found on my notes comes without the non-emtyness, but i made the stupid act of taking into account what is in the wikipedia)

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ open sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true. Here's a proof.

"$\Longrightarrow$"

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are germ-equivalent at $x$, so $A\cap U = B\cap U$ for some $U \in \xi (x)$. Then clearly $\mathbb{1}_A(y) = \mathbb{1}_B(y)$ for all $y \in U$. By definition we say that $\mathbb{1}_A$ is germ-equivalent to $\mathbb{1}_B$ at $x$.

"$\Longleftarrow$"

Now suppose that $\mathbb{1}_A(y) = \mathbb{1}_B(y)$ for all $y \in U$ for some $U \in \xi(x)$. Then clearly $A \cap U = B\cap U$, and by definition, $A$ is germ-equivalent to $B$ at $x$.

---

To put the argument more succinctly:
$$A \cap U = B \cap U \Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{1}_A(y) = \mathbb{1}_B(y), \,\, \forall y \in U$$

From which it follows that one germ-equivalence holds if and only if the other does.

Let me know if you need me to provide more details in either direction of the proof to be convincing.

Comment: by $U\in\xi(x)$ i mean U its a neighbourhood of $x$ so $\exists A\in\tau_1:x\in A\subseteq U$. But U doesn't have to be open. Also my question is not about open sets, but if there is some counterexamole i will be grateful to know it.

Comment: Okay, so you didn't mean an open neighborhood but the more general definition. Let me see if this proof still holds

Comment: I've modified it to be more general. The statement you make is true.

Comment: Ugh, I'm sorry, my definition was wrong. I wrote that at barely 2 am in the morning in my country. I'm going to edit it.

Comment: i'm sorry. But now the definitions are the right ones. My apologies for my dumbness.